# Considerations before I create WIX Merge Module for WCF Web Service Deployment

Tags: wcf, wix, installation

I want to deploy my WCF Web Service to IIS using WIX, I want to create a merge module project for this. I want to include this merge module in other main package? How can I do this? Any examples??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using to consume the merge module.  InstallShield?  WiX?  Other?  All of the above?

When it gets added to a product, is it always the same website / vdir / port  or can it be different?

This can be tricky and it might not be a job suitable for a merge module.  At a minimum I'd make two merge modules ( 1 for the files and 1 for the IIS extension pieces )  that way a product could consume the files but author their own IIS if needed.

If you are only doing WiX, fragments and libraries would be a better road to go down.  This way someone could reference the right set of component groups to get the same granularity.

Comment: We will use only WIX, we are not going to use any other.

Comment: Then you should be looking at Fragments and Libraries not Merge Modules.